# "Expected a type" errors using GeoFire with Firebase 3.2.1

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, geofire

I'm getting some errors after updating from Firebase 2.5.1.  It seems to me that GeoFire has lost some critical components, and being a beginner I am immediately lost. Has anyone seen this issue yet?

Below is a screenshot of my list of errors.
[image]

To add a little more info, here are the lines where the errors are occurring in GFQuery.h:

```
- (FirebaseHandle)observeEventType:(GFEventType)eventType withBlock:(GFQueryResultBlock)block;

- (FirebaseHandle)observeReadyWithBlock:(GFReadyBlock)block;

- (void)removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle:(FirebaseHandle)handle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current geofire version is not compatible with Firebase 3 the team is currently working in a compatible version

You can follow the issue here

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/37

Comment: Oh man, interesting.  So these are the standard errors people have been getting after trying to upgrade firebase?

Comment: Yep, and it is happening with goofier android and iOS as well as with android authentication.....if you really need to use geofire right now is recommended to still use the 2.5.1 version, or you could create your custom functionality by using Geohash  and queries... anyway the team is working fast to make this work

Comment: Yeah, I understand the big shift but this is pretty inconvenient. Any word on whether firebase will integrate its own GeoFire functionality, or will they continue to offer the frameworks separately?  Probably going to revert back to 2.5.1 for now.

Comment: The firebase team is behind GeoFire so it is its own GeoFire functionality, but they decided to make that library open source, so i don't think it will become part of firebase anytime soon... so far the updates and compatibility issues have been solved fast...but this time firebase really changed from the previous version.... good choice to keep the 2.5 for now...